# How do I code a fact with variable arguments?

Tags: prolog

Let's say I know the following:

> Wallace likes cheese AND inventing.
> Grommit also likes cheese.
> Wendolene likes sheep AND inventing.

I have a rule:

> Two people are friends if, and only if, they share at least one "like" in common.

So, Wallace and Grommit can be friends, because they both like cheese.
Wallace and Wendolene can both be friends because they both like inventing.

However, Grommit cannot be friends with Wendolene because he likes cheese, but not sheep or inventing, and she likes sheep and inventing, but not cheese.

How would I encode such a rule in Prolog?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need "variable arguments" for this. If Wallace likes cheese AND inventing, this is really short for saying that Wallace likes cheese AND Wallace likes inventing. These are two separate facts, and you can model them as separate facts in Prolog as well:

```
person_likes(wallace, cheese).
person_likes(wallace, inventing).
```